# How can i get the code of script file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are developing a web based application. In this we want to hide a script files from browser's page source. After some research we are planned to push the script files dynamically on browser page load, and also after page loaded we empty the source of the script files. 
        By using this method we are hide the script files from browser's page source.Is there any other method to get the script files.

Comment: No we cant hide the script data from the browser, since browser needs that to run the website.

Comment: You can compress them, making them obscure and harder to reverse engineer, but they have to go to the browser.

Comment: @BrianHoover is absolutely right. Besides, even if you will load scripts dynamically and and then wipe em out of page source, it is still one-click-deal to open any dev tool (commonly F12 key) and check corresponding server reply in Network (request list) tab to get all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *inline javascript* you can use *external files*. Your code will not be in the page you are viewing, but in another file. Of course it's not hidden from the browser.

Example for inline javascript:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("my super secret js!");
    </script>
</body>
```

Example for external file javascript:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your_js_file.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

```
/* your_js_file.js */
alert("my super secret js!");
```

Comment: yes,you are correct..am doing like that only..but in this am able to view the script file name from browser's page source(your_js_file.js). so that am dynamically create the source of the script file..on page load..after that am going to empty the script source attribute.. In that am getting the page source view like that..(<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>)..

Comment: so am hiding that source file name.. Is there any other method to get a script file name using browser's view

Comment: @user1422892 you should test that on various browsers, maybe a `right click-> view page source` will show the original source, before you empty the `src`.

Comment: Sharky,yes i checked that one by using browser inspect element.. and it shows <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>..

Comment: @user1422892 instead of an empty `src` just replace it with an empty file, for example `src="stats.js"` it will look less suspicious :D

Comment: @user1422892 if you want to hide your js from someone who will look your code, the `src=""` can look suspicious. so you can create for example an empty file `stats.js` and make your `src` look like this `src="stats.js"` it "looks" normal to the eyes of a programmer

Answer (score 0):

Simple! If you see source like : `<script type="text/javascript" src="xyz.js"></script>` in the browser's sorce window , then click on it and it will show you your javascript code!